# extracting elements of vector of named tuples into matrix in Julia

Tags: function, for-loop, julia

Suppose `results` is a vector of tuple with length `M` where `typeof(result) = Vector{NamedTuple{(:x, :p, :step), Tuple{Vector{Float64}, Float64, Int64}}}`.

`p` is also a vector of length `N` where `typeof(results[1].p) = Vector{Float64}`. I want to extract the first `N-1` elements of all the `p` inside `results` and express it as an `M x (N-1)` matrix. I know how to do it in a for loop, but is there a more element way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should both do what you ask but they return an `(N-1 x M)` matrix and I think they are very similar

```
hcat(map(x->x.p[1:N-1], results)...)

hcat([x.p[1:N-1] for x in results]...)
```

For the `(M x N-1)` output

```
vcat(map(x->x.p[1:N-1]', results)...)

vcat([x.p[1:N-1]' for x in results]...)
```

should work but it is a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional 2-loop comprehension may be 10X faster than `vcat` for this. You get an `M x (N-1)` matrix directly.

```
[results[i].p[j] for i=1:M, j=1:N-1]
```